# Github Enterprise with an IDE, Atom

Tags: git, github, ide, github-for-windows, github-enterprise

I've been trying for several hours now and I am probably overlooking something or doing something stupid.

I have a work PC with windows 10 and I installed, github desktop, Git (bash/gui/cmd) and Atom. I wanted to use atom as my IDE and avoid using github desktop (if necessary add some packages to atom).

Now I keep running into the problem that atom says that there are no remotes hosted at the repository; I'm sure there are as I can see them with github desktop as wel as online. Now I feel that the problem is because I need to use github enterprise as such I've tried cloning/pulling from here:
https://github.COMPANYNAMEHERE.be/myusernamehere/hello-world.git 
Ofcourse I removed the company name and directory.

The other error it gives is the following:

> remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations. remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key. remote: See
>   https://github.company.be/settings/tokens or
>   https://github.company.be/settings/ssh fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.company.be/myusername/hello-world.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

I had some other errors as well as I tried a bunch of stuff.

Can anyone help me out with either solving this problem.
Please note I'm not an ICT expert, I do some very simple linux, python and matlab coding because I need it for the research I'm doing. It's the plan to use github to better centralize information and scripts.

I want an IDE that I can simply run that can simply pull/fetch projects from GitHub Enterprise, let's me edit them properly with auto complete and color-coding, and let's me then commit them with necessary comments. I want to do this without having to swap between programs.

If some one has a good solution for Atom then I would love to read it if not I'll also be extremely happy with an IDE that can do what I need it to do.

Note: Running windows 10 and need to use GitHub Enterprise

Comment: Have you tried "VS code"? It is more maintained and also free, backed up by Microsoft and with a ton of plugins (git among them). On the other hand is really weird your error, since the connection is with git. Have you installed git for windows? can you do a clone without ide (git clone https://xxxxxxx)?

Comment: No but I've tried it now, got it to work in the end ;)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly why, probably has to do with locating the SSH keys or something but I was able to set it up in VS code with less problems.